# C++ Armadillo's connection with ATLAS/LAPACK

Tags: c++, lapack, armadillo, atlas

i'm running some C++ code that uses armadillo, 
i manually downloaded armadillo into the same folder.

while running the code i get:

```
       error: inv(): use of ATLAS or LAPACK needs to be enabled
```

what is the relation between armadillo and these libraries?

i'm searched google and didn't find a good solution or way to doenload any of these libraries.

i'm using kali linux 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Armadillo is, primarily, a C++ wrapper for low-level linear algebra libraries like LAPACK or ATLAS [Armadillo webpage with explanation of what it is](http://arma.sourceforge.net/). Since it's a wrapper, you need something to wrap, i.e. LAPACK etc. installed. Relevant piece of installation instruction (`README.txt`):

> On Linux systems it is recommended that the following libraries
>     are present: LAPACK, BLAS, ARPACK, SuperLU and ATLAS.
>     LAPACK and BLAS are the most important.  It is also necessary to
>     install the corresponding development files for each library.
>     For example, when installing the "lapack" package, also install
>     the "lapack-devel" or "lapack-dev" package.

I strongly advise reading the entire readme file.

LAPACK is a fairly popular library so it should be in your package repository.